# problem displaying Community password reset link error messages

Tags: visualforce, customer-community, error-messages

In our Community I am using custom Visualforce pages for login and reset password and the change password pages.

We occasionally have customers that the password reset link they get via email brings them back to the reset password request page with no error messages.  This of course causes a lot of confusion.

If using a password reset link that has expired or has already been used and using the default SFDC pages the page will show an error message to the user so at least they know what is happening.

I am trying to get my custom pages to display those same errors and not getting any results.  I have tried putting `<apex:pageMessages id="error"/>` on the page and this does not show any error messages.

This is an image of the error shown when using default password reset pages in SFDC 
[image]

This image shows the custom reset password page that is shown without any error messages

[image]

Comment: I was told by a product dev at SFDC that he did not know of any way to currently get these errors for use on the custom pages and he suggested to the product manager that this capability be added in the future.  I have been told things are not possible and later come across a solution so I am leaving this as a comment and not an answer hoping that a solution presents itself.

Comment: Thanks for updating this. I am currently in this situation as well at the moment. If you find a good solution to the problem please post it. I will as well.